# Error in retrieving cache token when executing connect-AzureRm command Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, talend

I'm running a powershell script which creates an azurerm connection and does some operation. So, when i run the script locally on the remote server the script, it works perfectly fine. But, i have an issue when i run the SAME script on talend connecting to the same remote server.
So, the error that i am in facing in talend is that, there is some issue retrieving  the token from cache. I've enclosed the error below

```
 DEBUG: 8:54:15 AM - ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand begin processing with ParameterSet 
 'ServicePrincipalWithSubscriptionId'.
 DEBUG: 8:54:15 AM - Autosave setting from startup session: 'CurrentUser'
 DEBUG: 8:54:15 AM - No autosave setting detected in environment variable 'AzureRmContextAutoSave'. 
 DEBUG: 8:54:15 AM - Using Autosave scope 'CurrentUser'
 DEBUG: [Common.Authentication]: Authenticating using configuration values: Domain: 
 'ca3451a2-786a-4345d-562a-36ed7dfc6a6', Endpoint: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/', ClientId: 
 '1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2', ClientRedirect: 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob', ResourceClientUri: 
 'https://management.core.windows.net/', ValidateAuthrity: 'True'
 DEBUG: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 
 DEBUG: 09/03/2018 08:54:15:  - AuthenticationContext: ADAL .NET with assembly version '2.28.3.860', file version 
 '2.28.31117.1411' and informational version '78bd21073cfd91768d97894ace1ba90c5b904eec' is running...
 DEBUG: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 
 DEBUG: 09/03/2018 08:54:15: 562ecf62-44e4-4a8c-936f-2aefds6c2d64f - AcquireTokenHandlerBase: === Token Acquisition 
 started:
  Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/ca3451a2-786a-4345d-562a-36ed7dfc6a6/
  Resource: https://management.core.windows.net/
  ClientId: ef34fabe-78b4-56tf-8677-0acde5caci0d6
  CacheType: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ProtectedFileTokenCache (0 items)
  Authentication Target: Client

 DEBUG: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 
 DEBUG: 09/03/2018 08:54:15:  - TokenCache: Deserialized 0 items to token cache.
 DEBUG: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Verbose: 1 : 
 DEBUG: 09/03/2018 08:54:15: 562ecf62-44e4-4a8c-936f-2aefds6c2d64f - TokenCache: Looking up cache for a token...
 DEBUG: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 
 DEBUG: 09/03/2018 08:54:15: 314e5662-7434-237c-956f-2aa8356cd64f - TokenCache: No matching token was found in the cache
 DEBUG: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Error: 4 : 
 DEBUG: 09/03/2018 08:54:15: 562ecf62-34e3-442c-936f-2aefds6c6fe78df - <RunAsync>d__0: 
 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: Service returned error. Check InnerException for 
 more details ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Comment: I suggest you remove AzureRM modules and install from scratch

Comment: I tried it but it didnt seem to help